# How to distinguish s from ş in a like search

Tags: mysql

I have a varchar column in a table in mysql. When I do a like search on this column, if I search like '%asd%', records which contain 'aşd' come up. Is there a way to prevent this?

I have tried with almost every collation possible, it behaves the same. Normally I use utf8mb4_unicode_ci.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the COLLATION to UTF8_BIN

```
    MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT
    ->         'aşd'  LIKE  'asd' COLLATE 'utf8_bin' AS BIN,
    ->         'aşd'  LIKE  'asd' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'  AS CI;
+------+------+
| BIN  | CI   |
+------+------+
|    0 |    1 |
+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

You also can put this in your WHERE Clause like

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE VARFIELD like 'asd' COLLATE 'utf8_bin';
```

Comment: I have tried setting the table collation to utf8_bin. It does not help. If I use `COLLATE` keyword in the query mysql gives `Unrecognized keyword. (near "COLLATE" at position 53)
Unexpected token. (near "'utf8_bin'" at position 61)`